# A book from the 80s/90s with a stage magician and a couple women

Tags: identification-request

I'm sorry but my memory is quite spotty on this but I'm obsessed with trying to remember this book. I don't remember the author or title at all. I barely remember a few things.

- the main character was a man who I think was a stage magician but there was always this ambiguity about whether or not the magic he did was real or if it was all just tricks. This wasn't a fantasy novel. It almost had a bit of psychic or occult feel.
- I seem to recall that a lot of the story revolved about this man and his relationship with two other women, sometimes at the same time.
- there was something on the back cover blurb about "sense of wonder"
- I have a vague recollection of the book cover. It was orange and blue (and green?). It may have been published by Penguin
- I read the book in the mid-1990s and there is a good chance that I bought this book at an English bookstore somewhere in Europe (Spain, Italy, or France).
- the edition of the book I had was a trade paperback
- the overall feel of the book seemed to be like Hemmingway (but not depressing) or the movie Vicky Cristina Barcelona.

That's about all I can remember now. Any hints at finding this book would be appreciated.

Comment: Was this book set in the present, or some different time? Do you remember where it was set?

Comment: IRRC, it was set in the present or close to the present. I don't feel like I solidly remember the setting but I think it was either East Coast US or Western Europe (or both).

Comment: Did the third book feature a scene where the protagonist had to make their way out of cavern with a parallel drawn to childbirth with him wriggling out of the tight entrance of the cavern, naked and covered in a mix of mud, blood, and his own fecal matter? The title might have referenced a gryphon?

Comment: Sounds like Robertson Davies's [Deptford Trilolgy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deptford_Trilogy).

Comment: That is it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @kimchilover If you want to write your own answer, feel free to crib as much as you'd like from mine. You were the one who found the answer.

Comment: @Mindxing: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. If kimchi lover posts their answer, especially if it's better than mine, you can always change which answer is the accepted one by clicking on another checkmark.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Thanks! But I'm content to leave things as they are: your answer is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kimchi lover posted the answer as a comment, and Mindxing confirmed it. Posting an answer so that it's evident that it has been answered.

[image: Comments showing answer provided, and acceptance]

This is Robertson Davies's [Deptford Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deptford_Trilogy), probably specifically the third book, *[Worlds of Wonder](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41098.World_of_Wonders)*:

[image: Front cover of the Penguin Classics edition of Worlds of Wonder]

> World of Wonders—the third book in the series after The Manticore—follows the story of Magnus Eisengrim—the most illustrious magician of his age—who is spirited away from his home by a member of a traveling sideshow, the Wanless World of Wonders. After honing his skills and becoming better known, Magnus unfurls his life’s courageous and adventurous tale in this third and final volume of a spectacular, soaring work.

Comment: Was this, indeed, the correct book of the trilogy, or were you looking for one of the other two?